# Replacing words in list of strings with a specific number (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, text

I want to translate 100 text strings to 100 series where each unique word is instead represented by its number.

I have a dictionary where each unique word in the 100 text strings have a corresponding number.

I also have a list with each text string.

I want to iterate over the list with text strings and identify every time the word in my dictionary-key is in the text string and then replace it with the corresponding number in my dictionary.

The code below is as far as I can go. But with this method I would have to make the for loop for every value in the list ft. Below is an example with dummy text.

```
# Create list with text to translate into numbers
    ft=list(['Consectetur quisquam aliquam quiquia adipisci ut labore ut sit eius etincidunt velit ipsum amet velit amet modi non quiquia quisquam adipisci dolor quiquia etincidunt quisquam dolore adipisci est quiquia quaerat neque consectetur sed non numquam porro aliquam sed voluptatem numquam consectetur magnam modi sit eius adipisci quisquam sed ut dolorem quisquam sit velit quisquam consectetur consectetur porro dolorem quiquia non dolore modi amet tempora etincidunt ut est sit quaerat dolorem consectetur etincidunt tempora velit voluptatem dolorem voluptatem sed modi ipsum labore adipisci tempora ipsum modi est non etincidunt porro sit etincidunt quaerat quisquam magnam quisquam aliquam modi aliquam aliquam est adipisci amet ipsum quaerat adipisci consectetur velit dolor quisquam non adipisci ipsum labore adipisci quisquam quaerat magnam eius voluptatem ut velit velit quaerat adipisci est non velit est labore labore eius magnam eius', 'Magnam aliquam tempora dolorem quaerat non quiquia numquam eius labore tempora ut neque dolor modi eius aliquam numquam quisquam ut sit est eius quisquam porro sed adipisci dolore porro amet eius sit adipisci sit dolore magnam neque sed modi tempora aliquam etincidunt quisquam dolor ipsum ut amet etincidunt consectetur non ipsum quisquam sed ipsum sit tempora consectetur sit consectetur velit etincidunt dolore labore adipisci ut dolor adipisci magnam sed quiquia etincidunt velit quisquam consectetur dolore ipsum modi sed est quiquia eius quisquam magnam voluptatem ut sit ut etincidunt dolore porro modi porro aliquam eius tempora neque porro eius dolorem etincidunt porro dolore quisquam quiquia quisquam quiquia sed quisquam consectetur ipsum ut tempora numquam adipisci'])

# Make dataframe in order to lower and to tokenize so that I can identify unique words

    df_ft = DataFrame(ft,columns=['Value'])
    new_ft =''.join(ft).lower()

    new_ft_token = word_tokenize(new_ft)
    unique=set(new_ft_token)

# Create a unique number and combine it to a dictionary    

    numbers = list(range(1,29))
    
    unique_list = list(unique)
    
    uni_dict = dict(zip(unik_liste, numbers))

# My attempt on a for loop substituting words with numbers 

    new_number_text = []
    
    for k, v in uni_dict.items():
        if k in ft[1]:
            new_number_text.append([k,v])
```

Comment: what is the need of `ft = list(['Consectertur ........'])` its already a list right?

Comment: Ig you meant `s = 'Conserctertur ....'; ft = list(s.split())`

Comment: @the__hat_guy thanks, that makes more sense!